# Flexible model with Elasticsearch and Tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

In Rails application I want to be able to store schema-less objects -- JSON data structure, that could have different structure from object to object, or for the same object at different times.

With ElasticSearch I can do this. However I would like to be use some kind of ORM with Rails for this.

Tried to do some testing with Tire tutorial, doing this in Rails console:

```
>>> c = Article.new :title =>'New article', :content => { :a => 'a', :b => 'b'}
```

I can see that content data stored as serialized YAML:

```
>> Article.last.content
=> "---\n:a: a\n:b: b\n"
```

This will require parsing search result to JSON, which is not a problem. But main question: will I be able to search inside serialized data? Is there a way to return attribute names from arbitrary structured data (like Object.keys)?

If not Tire, is there other solutions to do this?

Comment: This looks like good use for NoSQL, try CouchDB or Mongo. It will be more flexible instead hack SQL.

Comment: Well, ElasticSearch is NoSQL ...

Comment: @rado: Using elasticsearch for the outlined purpose is absolutely legitimate. Moreover, the original author never stated the intention to "hack SQL", nor is it evident from the code he posted.

Comment: @Dmytro i does not work with ElasticSearch. But if you want have schema-less objects, NoSQL are more preferable, because whole data are serialized and you can search all attributes.

Comment: @karmi sorry for my uncertain answer, i know that is legitimate. I want to only answer that nosql would be more practical for this issue

Comment: @rado, please see my previous comment. ElasticSearch **is NoSQL** :  it stores JSON schema-less objects, and whole data are serialized and I can search all attributes.

Comment: @Dmytro ahhh, i see it like opposite, sorry :)

Comment: @karmi Did it now, sorry still new to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you're up to here, but Tire does come with a drop-in replacement for ActiveRecord integration, just `include Tire::Model::Persistence` in your class. You may also define properties (with mappings, type casting, default values, etc):

```
class Article

  include Tire::Model::Persistence

  property :title
  property :published_on, type: 'date'
  property :tags,         analyzer: 'keyword', default: []

end
```

The *Tire* README and [integration tests](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/test/models/persistent_article_with_casting.rb) have all the info.

Of course you're able to search inside the `content` attribute -- it's just a matter of proper mapping.

If you're after some specific behaviour, please update your question...

Comment: Thank you, It looks like Persistence is what I need. Should always read README's to the bottom :)

Comment: So does the answer warrant accually accepting it, at the very least?